# How to get the values of an array of an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I have an array like this. Like array containing an array of objects.

```
posts = [
  [
    {
      "id": 2,
      "info": "This is some information"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "info": "This is the other information"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "id": 2,
      "info": "This is a duplicated id I want to remove"
    },
    {
      "id": 4,
      "info": "This information is safe"
    }
  ]
]
```

I want to get the elements from each array and create a new array that only has the objects at the same time removing duplicated ids.
What am trying to achieve is something like

```
posts = [
   {
      "id": 2,
      "info": "This is some information"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "info": "This is the other information"
    },
      {
      "id": 4,
      "info": "This information is safe"
    }
]
```

This is the code I have so far

```
id = ids.map(val => {
  for(let i in val) {
    console.log(val)
  }
return something
})
```

I keep getting undefined values. I have tried forEach, for loop.
Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) to get a flattened array of objects, and then [loop over the array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration#for...of_statement). If the current object's id can't be [found](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) in an object in the output array push that object.

```js
const posts=[[{id:2,info:"This is some information"},{id:3,info:"This is the other information"}],[{id:2,info:"This is a duplicated id I want to remove"},{id:4,info:"This information is safe"}]];

const out = [];

for (const obj of posts.flat()) {
  const found = out.find(f => obj.id === f.id);
  if (!found) out.push(obj);
}

console.log(out);
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I have no idea about flat. Now I know. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use `.flat()` and then `.filter()`:

```js
const posts = [
    [
        {
            id: 2,
            info: 'This is some information',
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            info: 'This is the other information',
        },
    ],
    [
        {
            id: 2,
            info: 'This is a duplicated id I want to remove',
        },
        {
            id: 4,
            info: 'This information is safe',
        },
    ],
];

const newPosts = posts.flat().filter((x, i, self) => i === self.findIndex((y) => x.id === y.id));

console.log(newPosts);
```

Another potential (and more optimal) solution could be this using `.reduce()`:

```js
const posts = [
    [
        {
            id: 2,
            info: 'This is some information',
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            info: 'This is the other information',
        },
    ],
    [
        {
            id: 2,
            info: 'This is a duplicated id I want to remove',
        },
        {
            id: 4,
            info: 'This information is safe',
        },
    ],
];

const newPosts = Object.values(posts.flat().reduce((acc, curr) => {
    return {
        ...acc,
        ...(!acc[curr.id] ? { [curr.id]: curr } : undefined),
    };
}, {}));

console.log(newPosts);
```

Or, if you don't like `.reduce()`, you can do something very similar with the `Map` object and a `for...of` loop:

```js
const posts = [
    [
        {
            id: 2,
            info: 'This is some information',
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            info: 'This is the other information',
        },
    ],
    [
        {
            id: 2,
            info: 'This is a duplicated id I want to remove',
        },
        {
            id: 4,
            info: 'This information is safe',
        },
    ],
];

const map = new Map();

for (const item of posts.flat()) {
    if (map.has(item.id)) continue;

    map.set(item.id, item);
}

const newPosts = Array.from(map.values());

console.log(newPosts);
```

Or even use a classic `for` loop to get the job done:

```js
const posts = [
    [
        {
            id: 2,
            info: 'This is some information',
        },
        {
            id: 3,
            info: 'This is the other information',
        },
    ],
    [
        {
            id: 2,
            info: 'This is a duplicated id I want to remove',
        },
        {
            id: 4,
            info: 'This information is safe',
        },
    ],
];

const flattened = posts.flat();
const map = {};

for (let i = 0; i < flattened.length; i++) {
    if (map[flattened[i].id]) continue;

    map[flattened[i].id] = flattened[i];
}

console.log(Object.values(map));
```

Either way, in each of these examples we're following the same workflow:

1. **Flatten** the array so that all items are on the same level.
2. **Filter** out the items with the duplicate IDs.

Answer (score 0):

I group by id in order to remove duplicates.

```js
var posts = [[{id:2,info:"This is some information"},{id:3,info:"This is the other information"}],[{id:2,info:"This is a duplicated id I want to remove"},{id:4,info:"This information is safe"}]];

var agg = {}
posts.forEach(function(arr) {
  arr.forEach(function(item) {
    agg[item.id] = agg[item.id] || item
  })
})

console.log(Object.values(agg))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important
}
```

Comment: the reduce could just be a forEach, also note that item.id will automatically be converted to string when it's used as an object key (no need for the `""+item.id`

Comment: code cleaned, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Flatten the array with [`flat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat), then use a set to keep track of the ids we already have. The ternary inside the `filter` is logic to check if the id is already in the set, and if it is, we filter the item out. Otherwise, we add the id back to the set.

```js
const posts = [[{id:2,info:"This is some information"},{id:3,info:"This is the other information"}],[{id:2,info:"This is a duplicated id I want to remove"},{id:4,info:"This information is safe"}]];

const flat = posts.flat();

const ids = new Set();

const filtered = flat.filter((item) => ids.has(item.id) ? false : ids.add(item.id));

console.log(filtered);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two things we need to do:

- Flatten the inner areas into one main array with `array.prototype.flat()`
- Remove duplicates based on, I'm assuming, the order of their appearance in the data.

  - We can do this by reducing the flattened array to an object with a condition that doesn't add any present id's if they're found
  - Then we convert that object to an array using `Object.values()`

```js
let posts = [ [ { "id": 2, "info": "This is some information" }, { "id": 3, "info": "This is the other information" } ], [ { "id": 2, "info": "This is a duplicated id I want to remove" }, { "id": 4, "info": "This information is safe" } ] ]

let flattened = posts.flat()
console.log('Flattened: ', flattened)

let unique = flattened.reduce((acc, obj) => {
  if (!acc[obj.id]) {
    acc[obj.id] = obj
  }
  return acc
}, {})
console.log('Unique Objects: ', unique)

let result = Object.values(unique)
console.log('Final Array: ' ,result)
```

Doing it in one go and with a spread `...` object merge:

```js
let posts = [ [ { "id": 2, "info": "This is some information" }, { "id": 3, "info": "This is the other information" } ], [ { "id": 2, "info": "This is a duplicated id I want to remove" }, { "id": 4, "info": "This information is safe" } ] ]

let result = Object.values(
  posts.flat().reduce((acc, obj) => 
    ({...{[obj.id]: obj}, ...acc})
  , {})
);
console.log('Final Array: ', result);
```